# ComboBox Items Disappearing while Re binding

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, combobox

In my application i have a combo-box with list of some data from DB. The combo-box data-source is given set to a binding source. The binding source has a data-set as Data-source and a Data-table as data-member.
I update this combo-box after adding or editing or deleting an entry. The updating is done by again calling the code for binding. Now all the items in the combo-box disappears.
I don't know how it happens.

A sample work is in the link http://www.filedropper.com/students_1. the db is included with it.

Comment: can you please, provide sample code of your server-side databinding and combo-box markup (i see the link to solution, buts thats very inconvenient and surplus info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code in 'void GetData()' write the code 
     bs = new BindingSource(new System.ComponentModel.Container()); 
  this has to be executed every time whenever you want to load new datasource

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your code so I can't give the exact solution but you can try with the following tip:
If you are calling your bind code inside if(!Page.IsPostback) block then remove from there and call on page load.